# Create my custom login block with Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

I'm in the process of learning Drupal 7 and i want to start with some basis. So basically, I want to create a login block that will take as input an emal adress and a password.

If the login is succesful, i want to display a user specific menu.

I'm using bartik template.

So my idea was to create a region called "login_region" and another region called "menus_region" to handle the display of the login form (login_region) and the menu (menus_region).

But I need some detailed pointers on the "clean" process to create the login form, process this form "on success: diplay the user menu", "onfailure, build a try again aler", check the unicity of the email adress etc...

I'm a php programer so I can easily do it in php but I want to do it the "drupal 7" way.

Answer (score 1):

You can Drupal's login block from the Block manager page `admin/structure/block`. You will find a block named `User login`, place it into the region you like.

If your intentions to get yourself into Drupal hooks, you will need to learn [how to create drupal modules](https://drupal.org/node/1074360). Then you will need to use few hooks to get what you need. [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7).

Your code should be something like:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_info()
 */
function myfirstmodule_block_info()
{
    $blocks = array();
    $blocks['blk1'] = array(
        'info'          => t("My Login Block"),
    );
    return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view()
 */
function myfirstmodule_block_view($delta = "")
{
    $block = array();

    switch($delta)
    {
        case "blk1":
            $loginForm = drupal_get_form("user_login");
            $block['subject'] = t("");
            $block['content'] = drupal_render($loginForm);
    }

    return $block;
}
```